# Copy report file back into Jenkins

Tags: apache, shell, jenkins, server, cobertura

I am trying to copy an XML file generated on an Apache server into the Jenkins workspace post-build. I was thinking to use a "send files over ssh" post-build script, but have not done this before and do not know how to refer to the file location on an Apache server versus on Jenkins.

For example, if I want to copy from Apache's location of: `classes/UnitTest/Results.xml` into Jenkin's workspace: `/ReportFiles/Results.xml`

How does the script differentiate between whether the location address refers to the Apache server or Jenkins workspace? Is there a better way to move files into Jenkins?

Comment: What's wrong with your initial idea about using `scp`? `scp report.xml user@jenkins.host:/ReportFiles/Results.xml`

Comment: this is what i needed: "user@jenkins.host:/ReportFiles/Results.xml", did not know how to specify that address location.